# RSA decrypt returns extra data

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I can decrypt some data encrypted via openssl command line tool, but some *'extra'* data is returned with the original data.
I've created a encrypted file like this:

$ echo this is it >file.txt

$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.pem -in file.txt -out encrypted.txt

And I can access the original data with:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = open('/tmp/.private.key').read()
rsakey = RSA.importKey(key, 'MyPassphrase')
data = open('/tmp/encrypted.txt', 'rb').read()
original = rsakey.decrypt(data)
```

But some extra data is returned and the output is something like this:

> \x02h\x83\xcfx\x84,\xb1\xa6 *[...]* \xcf5\x9f\xbbG\xf1\x14\xd0\x8d\x1f\xfe\x9c4\xbb\x1aB\xfa\xc3b\xc2\xe0K\x85\xb5\x10y\xe1\x8e\x00**this is this\n**

Can I avoid to receive this raw data before the decrypted data?

Obs.: The keys were created with openssl tool

Tks.

Comment: How exactly do you output `original`?

Comment: if ai print(original) it shows some binary with the data in the end:
**-VM-'~C M-fM-\ ~?~LPOZw^O^S^[M--M-:^WM-4M-,&IM-i^W6 ^\~I )M-B"^^_ ~_M-;G^TЍ^_M-~~\4M-;^ZBM-CbM-`K~EM-5^Py his is it**





I can do this to get the data:
rsakey.decrypt(data).split('\x00')[1] 

But I.m not sure if is the right way.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting PKCS#1 v1.5 padded plaintext back. You need to remove the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding first. Currently you are performing textbook (or "raw") RSA decryption, which is little more than modular exponentiation. Try a PKCS#1 v1.5 capable class instead, like [this one](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_Cipher-class.html)

Comment: Is it really only PKCS#1 v1.5? I always thought that the first byte must be always 0x00 and the second 0x02. This is not the case here.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Exactly what would happen if you don't convert the integer to an octet stream of fixed size, yes.

Comment: Hi, people. I'll try the module suggested by @MaartenBodewes.
Thanks by the help given! I appreciated it a lot.